# ¿como quitar el uso de WebView o cambiar para iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, webview

Actualmente se intenta subir una app a la tienda de Apple, para lo cual nos dieron la siguiente respuesta.

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview)

Hasta donde se sabe la app no hace uso de ningún **WebView**, por lo que puede que venga implementando en algún paquete.

las dependencias que actualmente se utilizan en el proyecto y que están dentro del archivo **pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  sqflite: ^1.1.6+1
  sqlite_bm25: ^0.2.0
  http: ^0.12.0+2 #Peticiones rest
  path_provider: ^1.1.0

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
 
  connectivity: ^0.4.3+6 
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+7
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+6
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.2
  flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.5.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+2
  splashscreen: ^1.2.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  crypto: ^2.1.2
  wakelock: ^0.1.4+1
```

**¿Alguna forma de saber que paquete utiliza el webView y como quitarlo o cambiarlo?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente el paquete `firebase_auth` usaba UIWebView hasta cierto punto ([Issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/3723)). Intenta revisar si estas usando la version mas reciente del componente. la version actual es [0.16.1](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth/)

Segun el historial este fix ya fue incluido, asi que cambiandolo a la ultima version deberia solucionarlo (sin olvidar ejecutar pod update).

Si deseas comprobar el uso de UIWebVIew, y tienes acceso a abrir el proyecto en xCode, puedes ir a la seccion "Frameworks" y chequear si existe `UIKit.framework`

Esta es la [lista de paquetes que dependen de firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages?q=dependency%3Afirebase_auth) si piensas en la posibilidad de simplemente descartarlo.

Comment: ok.. lo actualizo, pero existe alguna forma de verificar que la nueva actualización utiliza lo que pide Apple?.

Comment: O existe alguna forma de eliminar unicamente ese complemento ?

Comment: Agregue mas informacion. Puedes hacer un chequeo adicional antes de enviarlo otra vez (es un poco burocratico por parte de Apple, lo se)